# How to find a correct path in Swift

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, database-connection

I got this code from the documentation, I can't find the path to my file, I need to copy the "contacts.db" file from Supporting Files Folder to the app in the device not in the simulator for offline use.

```
func copyItemAtPath(_ srcPath: String,
         toPath dstPath: String,
          error error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool
```

srcPath = The path to the file or directory you want to move. This parameter must not be nil.
dstPath = The path at which to place the copy of srcPath. This path must include the name of the file or directory in its new location. This parameter must not be nil.
error = On input, a pointer to an error object. If an error occurs, this pointer is set to an actual error object containing the error information. You may specify nil for this parameter if you do not want the error information.

Any help is highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just drag and drop "contacts.db" into Project Navigator and after that you can find a path of that file this way:

```
let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("contacts", ofType: "db")
```

after that you can copy that file into document folder of your app and for that you need that document folder path:

```
let doumentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
let destinationPath = doumentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("contacts1.db")
```

now you have `sourcePath` and `destinationPath` so you can copy that file into document folder:

```
NSFileManager().copyItemAtPath(sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath, error: &error)
```

and if you want to check for error you can do it this way:

```
var error : NSError?
    NSFileManager().copyItemAtPath(sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath, error: &error)
    if let error = error {
        println(error.description)
    }
```

If you are getting your `sourcePath` nil then goto Targets->YouApp->Build Phases->copy Bundle Resources and add your file there.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Dharmesh, thanks for the detailed reply, I copied all your code to delegate.swift, but got many errors below. I am using FMDB is there a problem?

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x1740ef600 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BCD1A88D-DCAB-4A4D-90F3-B1C0FC99525B/Database-Book.app/contacts.db, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
),

Comment: NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8079789-BEE7-4C3A-A980-C794B05454B6/Documents/contacts.db, NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BCD1A88D-DCAB-4A4D-90F3-B1C0FC99525B/Database-Book.app/contacts.db, NSUnderlyingError=0x174059170 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}

Comment: I deleted the file, and added via build phase but the same error :( any suggestion?

Comment: check this sample project: https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Copy-db-file-from-resources

Comment: Thank you for your time, worked very well. Minor issues I will try to solve by myself :)